# unable to create month through shell script

Tags: java, spring, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to create path to archive files through shell script in the path

```
/folder1/folder2/archive/YYYY/MM/incoming
```

The shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKUP_DIR=/folder1/folder2/archieve
YEAR_DIR=$(date +%Y)
MON_DIR=$(date +%m)

echo "Creating archive folder!!!"

mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}/${YEAR_DIR}/${MON_DIR}/incoming"
mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}/${YEAR_DIR}/${MON_DIR}/outgoing"
mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}/${YEAR_DIR}/${MON_DIR}/FAILED"
```

Also in application.properties file I have below configuration:

application.properties.xml

```
#Config for file locations

#spring.archiving.filePath= /folder1/folder2/archieve/YYYY/MM/incoming
#spring.archiving.backup.filePath=/folder1/folder2/archieve/YYYY/MM/outgoing
#spring.archiving.failed.filePath= /folder1/folder2/archieve/YYYY/MM/FAILED
```

Yet java is taking `/YYYY/M/` It is creating folder for months with 2 digits like `November(11)` `December(12)`. But for `January` it uses `1` instead of `01`.  Hence the files not getting archived to the correct location. Can anyone help in this? What is wrong with shell script or with application.properties file? I am using spring boot application.

```
 **Java is handling this as below:**
 //Process method reads the archieving path mentioned in properties.xml file 

  public void process(Mapper mapper) {
            this.archivingFilepath = 
            this.renameFilePathWithDate(this.archivingFilepath);
  }
  **This method helps to rename file path with year and month**

    public String renameFilePathWithDate(String filePath) {

            final String yearString = "YYYY";//creating variables for year 
  and month
            final String monthString = "MM";
            Date date = new Date();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            String newFilePath = filePath.replaceAll(yearString, 
           String.valueOf(year));
            newFilePath = newFilePath.replaceAll(monthString, 
            String.valueOf(month));
            return newFilePath;
        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What actual shell are you using? Is it _really_ `sh` or `bash` under the covers? How do you pass the date to the Java code, and what Java code uses the month?  As far as I can tell, the `date +%m` returns a string in the range `01..12` with the leading zero.  If the problem is in the Java code you need to include that in your question.

Comment: the java date , month is from 0-11 . Thus, if firstly you should use (month +1) in java. Also after tis, convert month to String and append 0 for 1-9. Alternatively try to month in format MON (E.g: JAN, FEb etc) that will save headache

Comment: In my java application,there is application.properties whcih has the configuration as below:.#Config for file locations

#spring.archiving.filePath= /folder1/folder2/archieve/YYYY/MM/incoming
#spring.archiving.backup.filePath=/folder1/folder2/archieve/YYYY/MM/outgoing
#spring.archiving.failed.filePath= /folder1/folder2/archieve/YYYY/MM/FAILED

Comment: @akshayapandey i did not get what you are saying.Like for the month of december I was able to create path if you are saying month is from 0-11.In java I have used application.properties file with path mentioning month as MM.What else needs to be changed in java?

Comment: There's a whole section missing from your question where you show us how the Java program is invoked (where's the `java` command in the shell script) and then the part where the Java program reads the properties and substitutes the month into the value. And BTW, you call it `application.properties.xml` but the data looks like regular properties ***that are commented out***.  There's so much missing and unclear here that the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @JimGarrison. Sorry i missed to put the java part.Please find my java code here.this gets path from application.properties file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code there.

Comment: @JimGarrison edited

Comment: I have understood what the issue is.                                                            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;//This gives current month as 1 not 01.Can anybody suggest what api I should use to get 01 instaed of 1 for month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is your problem:

```
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

ints are not stored as 2 digit characters, both 01 and 1 are stored as 1. if you want to do that, write the following:

```
int month = cal.get(new DecimalFormat("00").format(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using------>                                                                            
                 int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
  String formattedmonth = String.format("%02d", month);                         Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well i can't stop you from using dinosaur code ;) you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
String.format(                                            // Make text of a number.
    "%02d" ,                                              // Pad with leading zero for January-September.
    ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )  // Get current moment in a particular time zone.
                 .getMonthValue()                         // Interrogate for the number of the month.
)
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

And you are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass  as an argument. Omitting the zone causes the JVM’s current default to be applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Get current moment for that zone by instantiating a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want the year and month as strings, interrogate for the `int` and format. Note that months have sane numbering in java.time, 1-12 for January-December, unlike the legacy date-time classes.

```
String year = String.format( "%04d" , zdt.getYear() ) ;  // Obviously not needed for contemporary years, but FYI.
String month = String.format( "%02d" , zdt.getMonthValue() ) ; // Pad with leading zero for single-digit months January-September.
```

By the way, you might find year-month useful in such work. The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents such a thing, and the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines the textual format `YYYY-MM`. You may also be interested in the classes [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) and [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html).

```
String yearMonth = YearMonth.from( zdt ).toString() ;  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM.
```